# Set all instances of a value to null in Realtime Database: Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to take wipe all of the values of a particular userID connected to many different post keys in my database by turning the userID to null. The userIDs are attached to post keys in the path: posts/ivies/userIDs in my database. Here is how the database looks:

[image: Database Structure]

So I decided to run the following for loop to filter for the userID and turn it to null:

```
exports.wipeData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
 const original = 'ppPXA8MvaSRVbmksof0ByOzTxJ92';
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/posts/ivies/userIDs/');
    console.log((snapshot));

    for (let value in snapshot.val) {
      if (value == original) {
      snapshot.val.set("null")
      }
      else {
        console.log(value)
      }
    }

    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());

// [END adminSdkPush]
});
```

Although this function deploys and runs, it does not turn 'ppPXA8MvaSRVbmksof0ByOzTxJ92' to 'null' as anticipated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach seems fine, but you have a few bugs in there.

This should work better:

```
exports.wipeData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const original = 'ppPXA8MvaSRVbmksof0ByOzTxJ92';
  const ref = admin.database().ref('/posts/ivies/userIDs/');
  const query = ref.orderByValue().equalTo(original);

  const results = await query.once('value');
  const updates = {};
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    updates[snapshot.key] = null;
  });

  await ref.update(updates);

  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(updates));
})
```

The main changes:

- Your `snapshot` variable doesn't contain any data yet, as you're not reading from the database. The `once('value')` in my code performs that read.
- This code uses a query to select only the nodes that have the right value. When your number of users grows, this significantly reduces the database load (and cost).
- This code first gathers all updates into a single object, and then sends them to the database as one call.
- The `await` in `await ref.update(updates)` is probably the main fix, as it ensures the redirect is only executed once the database writes has been completed.

Comment: Hmm. Your function is throwing a 403 "Your client does not have permission to get URL /%7B%7D from this server" when I try to run the function with the URL "https://us-central1-<ProjectID>.cloudfunctions.net/wipeData". wipeData still runs according to server logs, but the IDs stay in the database

Comment: Note that I am the owner of the database and the function finishes with a status code 303

Comment: Ah, I realize now my code sends a regular response in the redirect body. I'd probably use a `res.send()` to test, and then whatever redirect you want for production. The more important part about the changes I made to your code is hopefully clear from my bullet by bullet explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with firebase cloud functions, but in regular client-side firebase code `val` needs to be called as a function, and you have to wait for the value from a reference. You could try:

```
exports.wipeData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const original = 'ppPXA8MvaSRVbmksof0ByOzTxJ92';
  const userIDs = await admin.database().ref('/posts/ivies/userIDs/');
  userIDs.once("value", snapshot => {
    var lookup = snapshot.val();
    for (let key in lookup) {
      var value = lookup[key];
      if (key == value) {
        userIDs.child(key).set(null);
      }
    }
    res.redirect(303, userIDs.ref.toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code finished with status code 303 and did not update the keys

Comment: Oh, oops, my code was wrong, I didn't read the question clearly enough. I changed it so I compare against the value instead of the key now. I would still be surprised if it works, but hopefully it gets you closer to what you need.

Comment: Your redirect still happens before the writes have completed, which means they get aborted. Lou'll need a `Promise.all()` on all the set operations to ensure the writes complete before the redirect happens.